# How to select the nth row of an sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This must be so easy but I'm having trouble. Can someone provide the code lines to print the data from an nth row of a select query?

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Table")

$num = 5;

//Print array of the 5th row
???

//Print the value of column Name of 5th row
???
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: `printr_r($sql[4])` because PHP start with 0 index

Comment: @zimorok but $sql is likely to be a result object not a plain array. That's how most of PHP's database libraries work. OP just needs to view some examples of fetching results for their chosen library.